# How important are those fields of chemistry in biotechnology and medicinal chemistry

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, medicinal-chemistry

At my university there is some fields of chemistry that i don't know if i should focus on them...

How important are in biotechnology and medicinal chemistry those fields of chemistry? :

1. Quantum chemistry
2. Physical chemistry
3. Computional chemistry

Comment: Computional chemistry - for computer aided drug design

Comment: I would say the three are linked and you can't study only one and ignore the other two. I mean, how are you going to do anything in quantum chemistry without computer calculations, for example?

Comment: Physical chemistry is a massive field with no clearly delineated boundaries. Arguably protein mass spec and protein NMR are disciplines of physical chemistry (and thus huge amounts of biotechnology). You could also argue that biological soft matter is a physical chemistry discipline.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is broad and these chemistry which you have pointed out in your question is interlinked (Quantum ,Physical and Computational chemistry). The best way which I can explain this question is by giving links to main research carried out using these chemistry in biological science.

The study of quantum mechanics in photosynthesis is one such area and this [nature paper(Nature 446, 782-786 (12 April 2007)](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v446/n7137/full/nature05678.html) is about that research

the highlights of the paper is the evidence for wavelike energy transfer through quantum coherence in photosynthetic systems

> two-dimensional electronic spectroscopy investigations of the FMO
>   bacteriochlorophyll complex, and obtain direct evidence for remarkably
>   long-lived electronic quantum coherence playing an important part in
>   energy transfer processes within this system. The quantum coherence
>   manifests itself in characteristic, directly observable quantum
>   beating signals among the excitons within the Chlorobium tepidum FMO
>   complex at 77 K. This wavelike characteristic of the energy transfer
>   within the photosynthetic complex can explain its extreme efficiency,
>   in that it allows the complexes to sample vast areas of phase space to
>   find the most efficient path.

Other useful links

[Nature 431, 256-257 (16 September 2004)](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v431/n7006/full/431256a.html)

[Nature 446, 740-741 (12 April 2007)](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v446/n7137/full/446740a.html)